# Unity DontDestroyOnLoad function for multiple objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

DontDestroyOnLoad script for mutliple objects, Without the objects being duplicated.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaBjr.png)
I tried using this script, But it only works on one object, Whenever I use it for another object the first one gets destroyed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Post code as text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why using a singleton pattern? If you want multiple objects .. well remove that static thing and everything related to it - including destroying other instances ...

Answer (score -1):

You can follow these:

1- Create an object to the scene and add this script to this object.

```cs
    public static YourClass Instance;
    private void Awake()
    {
      DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
      if (Instance != null && Instance != this) 
      { 
        Destroy(this);
      } 
      else 
      { 
        Instance = this; 
      } 
    }
```

2- Then all you need to do is put anything you want to make Singleton and DontDestroy under this parent object in the hierarchy. Please check this image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmIPG.png)

**Note That:** If you want to make singleton two different objects in two different scenes, then you need to create another class.

Comment: This ( the script u sent ) duplicates the object when the scene is being restarted. I am new to programming I still don't know how to make parent object.

Comment: This ( the script u sent ) duplicates the object when the same scene is loaded again, I want it that when the same scene is being loaded again or the same object exists in the next scene ,the first one created stays and the second one created gets destroyed  . I am new to programming I still don't know how to make parent object.

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope this will help your problem:)

Comment: I created another class, Thanks.